# Server 2003 not pinging and remotely connecting

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a windows server 2003 configured as DC web server, file server, and anti virus server using Kaspersky security center. I have configure one manageable switch, one N/W printer and 13 clients on the N/W. I also configured the server for NAT. Everything was working fine suddenly my server not getting pinged from client side and also not able to connect the server using RDC. My web site is (Http) working fine. my ftp is working fine. i can access my switch and N/W printer from sever as well as clients. My server is not pinging from any client and some of my client is not pinging from server. i can ping the switch, Printer and some clients. my shared folder in server is not visible/accessible from client as i was using it as a maped N/W drive on clients. when i am opening the shared folder by using serverip/folder name it is getting open but the folders in it are not visible.

pls give me a solution for this

i want to share the folder 
i want to use the remote desktop Connection of server from client side

Thank you

Comment: are you pinging by IP address or name?

Comment: tried with both ip and name

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall rules.  I remember that RDP and ICMP were blocked by the default Kaspersky policy last time I set it up.